# USB 3.0 without controller/mux

Tags: schematics, usb-c

I am currently designing an interface board for the Jetson Orin Nano which will go into a commercial product. Part of the design includes a connection to a USB 3.0 camera ([UVCI-AR0822-SL](https://www.technexion.com/products/embedded-vision/usb3-camera/uvci-ar0822-sl/) to be specific). The camera will have its dedicated USB port which will only be used for that purpose.

As the design will be constrained in terms of space, my idea is to leave out the USB-C controller and multiplexer. Instead, I was planning to pull up both CC lines with 56kOhm resistors (advertising default USB power, 0.9A @ 5V) and to connect only two of the SS pairs (flipping the cable between the interface board and camera if needed).

I should mention that once everything is connected, it will not be accessible to the user, so the requirements for protection are not very strict.

Here is a rough schematic:

[image: rough schematic]

Will this setup work? Do you have any suggestions for improvements?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I understand that you are not making an user accessible USB-C port and it might not need to be compliant, and that certainly isn't. If you don't support both orientations then why bother with two pull-up resistors. Also the receptacle is not allowed to output 5V until a device is connected. And USB2 link is missing. Would it be simpler to be compliant and implement Type-A receptacle? Right now it seems a Type-A receptacle is exchanged to Type-C without considering the differences.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, all of the points you make are valid.

Adding two resistors is less work than adding a controller, also I am assuming that the camera is connected and stays connected as long as the system is powered on. As for the USB2 link, as far as I understand it is not used in normal circumstances and only as a backup when there is no connection through the SS lines. (Correct me if I'm wrong on any of this.)

Assuming I change the receptacle to a Type-A, how is the multiplexing of the SS lines handled? If I stay with the current setup, is there any benefit of Type-A?

Comment: Yes but the other resistor is useless as you only support one orientation, why say to camera that host is connected in the unsupported orientation. Type-A does not need multiplexing of SS lines, the plug goes in only one way. Some cameras use both USB4 and USB2, 3 for data and 2 for control. Who knows how your camera works.